# error de JavaScript en pagespeed

Tags: javascript, seo, googlepagespeed

hola tengo el siguiente problema realizando el seo de mi pagina web en pagespeed, me arroja el siguiente error en la versión móvil

ReferenceError: data_pais is not defined at mone_pais_usada

pero entro a la versión web y esta sin errores, y en la consola de mi pagina todo va sin problema ni errores,  e incluso el error hace referencia  a que en la funcion moneda_pais_usada no esta definida data_pais que es un JSON  y pues coloco justo al inicio de esa funcion mi console.log(data_pais) y efectivamente me muestra los datos del json sin problema alguno pero lo que me frustra es ver que en pagespeed me dice que según tengo ese error